# How to make a form remember what was selected in a form with PHP?

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a form that validates the information submitted within a form, method is POST and is submitted to another file "Check.php", I am using sessions to remember what the POST data is, when ever there is a problem with the form I redirect it back to the form input page.

How do you get the post data to remember which OPTION was selected in the SELECT input?

CODE:

```
<select name="referred">
    <option value="facebook">facebook</option>
    <option value="youtube">youtube</option>
    <option value="reddit">reddit</option>
    <option value="google">google</option>
</select>
```

I've tried to do this but does not work:

```
<select name="referred">
    <option value="facebook"   
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['referred']) && $_POST['referred'] == "Facebook") {
            print "selected=\'selected\'";
        } 
    ?>?> >facebook</option>
```

I've tried to do this but still, does not work :(

```
<select name="referred">
    <option value="facebook"
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['referred'])) {
            if ($_POST['referred'] == "youtube") { 
                echo "selected=\'selected\'";
            } else {
                echo "";
            }
        }
    ?> >facebook
```

Please help!

**EDIT:**

I APOLOGISE, I'm not using the $_POST here to check if it's set, I should be using the $_SESSION, see below:

```
            <select name="referred">
                <option name="google"<?php if(isset($_SESSION['referred'])){ if($_SESSION['referred'] == "google"){ echo "selected='selected'";}else{ echo "";}}?>>google</option>
                <option name="youtube"<?php if(isset($_SESSION['referred'])){ if($_SESSION['referred'] == "youtube"){ echo "selected='selected'";}else{ echo "";}}?>>youtube</option>
                <option name="reddit" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['referred'])){ if($_SESSION['referred'] == "reddit"){ echo "selected='selected'";}else{ echo "";}}?>>reddit</option>
                <option name="facebook" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['referred'])){ if($_SESSION['referred'] == "facebook"){ echo "selected='selected'";}else{ echo "";}}?>>facebook</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: this code is bloated as hell. why `else` statement?

Comment: and that useless `name` property in the options

Comment: I wanted to make sure nothing would appear, but I see your point and the else statement is definitely not needed.

Mate you are spot on with the name property, my bad, I wasn't very sure which property the post data would pick up, so I did both, you're very correct in that it is useless. thanks I'll clean it up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to escape single quotes in a string wrapped in *double quotes*.

```
echo "selected=\'selected\'" // incorrect
```

Like that your html markup would end up like `<option value="facebook" selected=\'selected'\>` Which is bad html.

This should work.

EDIT

```
<select name="referred">
    <?php
        if (!empty($_SESSION['referred']) && 'option1' == $_SESSION['referred']) {
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';
        } else {
            $selected = null;
        }
    ?>
    <option value="option1" <?= $selected; ?>>option1</option>
    ....
</select>
```

If you have a known set of options then make an array and loop through them:

```
<?php
    $options = array(
        'option1' => 'Option 1',
        'option2' => 'Option 2',
        'option3' => 'Option 3' // ...
    );
    $referredIsset = isset($_SESSION['referred']);
?>

<select name="referred">
    <?php foreach ($options as $value => $name): ?>
        <?php
            $sel = ($referredIsset && $_SESSION['referred'] == $value)
                ? 'selected="selected"'
                : null;
        ?>
        <option value="<?= $value; ?>" <?= $sel; ?>>
            <?= $name; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this website. 

I just want to essential do this: 
<select name="referred">
<option name="option1" * I want php to check if $_SESSION['referred'] is set then Check if it matches "option1" if so echo "selected='selected'" *   > option1</option>

So that if the session is set and the option is equal to 'option1' then echo the html code to made it selected, hope that made sense.

Comment: Ok check my edit.. Is that what you were looking for? If you're looking to do this for _all of your options_ then maybe it would be best to store them in an array and loop through that array.

Comment: Umm who just downvoted this? Care to comment? I see no valid reason to downvote this.

Comment: YES, that worked, You're a legend, I'm going to take something for my headache and sing your name in the shower. 

I've seriously been trying to do this for days, You sir are a legend, if you're ever in Melbourne - Australia, the drinks are on me! 

Thank you mmmshuddup so much for your help!

Comment: lol you're welcome and thanks for the offer. Now I just want to figure out who downvoted my answer and why :S.  Cheers!

Comment: You're very welcome. I wish I could upvote but it won't let me as I'm a fresh account. 

I can't understand why you would be downvoted, everything you mentioned and especially the array version certainly is correct from the research I've done, they all mention the use of arrays instead, including the people that posted here.

Answer (score 1):

separate your business logic from presentation logic
define your variables.
avoid repetitions.

the code

```
$form['referred'] = array('facebook','youtube','reddit','google');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
  //form validations
  //if failed, fill variables with actual values
  $form['ref'] = $_POST['referred'];
} else {
  //filling variables with empty values
  $form['ref'] = '';
}
```

the template

```
<select name="referred"> 
<? foreach($form['referred'] as $val): ?>
  <option<? if($form['ref'] == $val):?> selected="selected"<? endif ?>><?=$val?></option> 
<? endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Comment: could be done with the ternary operator. apart from that, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

First of all var_dump($_POST); to see what you get after submitting your form.

(You don't need the SESSION to store your POST data. Everything you need is in $_POST. And if an error occurs you can redirect to your form without the need to store the information additionally in the session.)

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your reply.

When I select an option and echo the $_POST['reffered'] it gives me the name "youtube".

The set up is as followed: 

Registration Form Submit -> Check.php -> All validation is made, if any errors it redirects back to Registration form, hence the use of sessions because doesn't $_POST only send data to the next location it doesn't store it like a session right? so $_POST['referred'] = $_SESSION['referred']

Comment: I understood that you redirect to an other file. But why should you do that if your code for the form is in the other (or why it is not in a template); both could be included without the need for session stroing.